# AsyncTask with result of ArrayList of objects is returning null in OnPostExecute

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask

I'm trying to retrieve some data from API, but i'm always getting null in async task. Here is my asynctask:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, List<Topic>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        HomeActivity.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        HomeActivity.mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Topic> doInBackground(Bundle... params) {
        return downloadPhotos(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Topic> topics) {
        HomeActivity.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        HomeActivity.mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);

        Log.d("List Size: ", ""+topics); // 0

        adapter = new TopicListAdapter(activity, topics);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new MyCustomLayoutManager(activity);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Method for retrieving data should merge two arrays into one array because i'm retrieving data from two places:

```
private List<Topic> downloadPhotos(Bundle params) {
    String profileId = activity.getPreferencesManager().getProfileId();
    List<Topic> topicsFromMe, topicsFromFriends;
    topicsFromFriends = setValuesFromFriends(params);
    topicsFromMe = setValuesFromMe(profileId, params);
    topicsFromFriends.addAll(topicsFromMe);
    sortTopics(topicsFromFriends);
    int k = topicsFromFriends.size();
    Log.d("List Size: ", "" + topicsFromFriends); // here also 0 for size
    if (k > 10)
        topicsFromFriends.subList(10, k).clear();
    return topicsFromFriends;
}
```

And here is one method where i'm setting values to array list. It is strange that RecyclerView in this case is populated with this array, but i'm not getting results i want. For instance i should sort this list and show only 10 records from it.

```
private List<Topic> setValuesFromFriends(final Bundle params) {
    final List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    activity.getSimpleFacebook().getFriends(new OnFriendsListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
            for (final Profile profile : friends) {
                activity.getSimpleFacebook().get(profile.getId(), "photos/uploaded", params,
                        new OnActionListener<List<Photo>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(List<Photo> photos) {
                                for (final Photo photo : photos) {
                                    // Initialize instance of Topic
                                    final User user = photo.getFrom();
                                    final Topic topic = new Topic();

                                    topic.setCaption(photo.getName());
                                    topic.setImageId(photo.getId());
                                    topic.setCreatedTime(photo.getCreatedTime());
                                    topic.setPostImage(photo.getSource());
                                    topic.setUserId(user.getId());
                                    topic.setName(user.getName());

                                    final Bundle likeParams = new Bundle();
                                    likeParams.putString("fields", "total_count");
                                    likeParams.putString("limit", "100000");

                                    activity.getSimpleFacebook().get(photo.getId(), "likes",
                                            likeParams, new OnActionListener<List<Like>>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(List<Like> likes) {
                                                    topic.setNumOfLikes(likes.size());
                                                    topics.add(topic);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onThinking() {
                                                    super.onThinking();
                                                }
                                            });

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
    return topics;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using AsyncTask incorrectly.

AsyncTask is launching another Thread (thread1) where where it is executing the method, `doenloadPhotos`. This method is calling `setValuesFromFriends` which is creating another thread (thread2) with the method `getFriends`. As thread2 has been launched, the rest of the code in `setValuesFromFriends` will get executed.

So here is how it is working:

```
private List<Topic> setValuesFromFriends(final Bundle params) {
    final List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    //launched process on new thread
    return topics; //this is 0 as topics = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So now  `topicsFromFriends = 0`. Hence you are getting the output = 0.

in effect thread1 is getting executed before thread2 is complete. As the output of thread1 is 0, nothing is displayed in UI after `onPostExecute`

There is no need of using AsyncTask.
You should put all the required code inside the `onComplete` of the `new OnFriendsListener()`. This way the info will be shown correctly. You can launch the progressbar before `setValuesFromFriends` and then remove it in the `onComplete`.